# Как определить размер экрана при смене ориентации девайса?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Например я начал смотреть в телефоне сайт. Затем я его перевернул и картинка уже обрезана.

Как определить в jquery, что я сменил ориентацию телефона?

Или скажем сменил размер окна браузера?

Как это определить без перезагрузки страницы?

Comment: Вероятно подписаться на что-то типа DeviceOrientationEvent or DeviceOrientationAbsoluteEvent. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/device-orientation-changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот это с помощью `jQuery`:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    console.log($(window).width());
});
```

Вообще есть событие `resize` и оно работает как при простого изменение размера окна так и возникает и при смене ориентации.

А так вы отследите только изменение ориентации:

```
$(window).on('orientationchange',function(){
    console.log('uraaa');
});
```

Это событие `orientationchange`.

Добавил пример после комментариев автора.

```
$( window ).load( function(){

   w = $( window ).width();

});

$( window ).resize( function(){

  if( w != $( window ).width() ){

    //Здесь ваша логика.

  }

});
```

Comment: А как теперь определить что менялась только ширина?

Comment: @vKs Давайте подробный вопрос и тогда смогу помочь. и еще одно для чего тебе разные события для этих двух? все ровно в обоих случаях ширина меняется.

Comment: Мне нужно, что бы страница перегружалась, когда была изменена только ширина окна браузера или сменена ориентация телефона.
Даный пример также срабатывает и при изминении высоты окна, что очень плохо

Comment: @vKs обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Answer (score 2):

Для определения события поворота экрана существует событие [`orientationchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/orientationchange)

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
    alert("Размер окна теперь равен " + window.width + "px");
});
```

Для определения события изменения размера окна браузера существует событие [`resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize)

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    alert("Размер окна теперь равен " + window.width + "px");
});
```

Поскольку событие `resize` выстреливает с большой частотой, существует техника, ограничивающее частоту срабатываний для оптимизации производительности.

Вот один из способов на основе [`requestAnimationFrame`](http://requestAnimationFrame):

```
(function() {
    var throttle = function(type, name, obj) {
        obj = obj || window;
        var running = false;
        var func = function() {
            if (running) { return; }
            running = true;
             requestAnimationFrame(function() {
                obj.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(name));
                running = false;
            });
        };
        obj.addEventListener(type, func);
    };

    /* init - you can init any event */
    throttle("resize", "optimizedResize");
})();

// handle event
window.addEventListener("optimizedResize", function() {
    console.log("Да здравствует разумная утилизация ресурсов!");
});
```

Comment: А как теперь определить что менялась только ширина?

Comment: @vKs, например, при событии `window.addEventListener("load", function() {});` запомнить высоту и сравнивать ее в указанных событиях с эталонной. Однако при `orientationchange` она по-любому будет меняться.

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь все работает как надо